# search bar method for array of dictionarys in ios using NSPredicate method

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am new in IOS and I am creating a search bar for `UITableView`. It is working fine when I use an array directly, but when I have an array with a dictionary it's not working.

I have an array of dictionaries:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSMutableDictionary    *person1 = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:@{
                            @"Name" : @"john",
                            @"Age" : @"10"
                            }];
    NSMutableDictionary  *person2  = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:@{
                        @"Name" : @"piter",
                        @"Age" : @"22"
                                   }];
    NSMutableDictionary *person3  = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:@{
                        @"Name" : @"rams",
                        @"Age" : @"23"                                                                          
                                      }];

    self.person = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:person1,person2,person3 ,nil];
}
```

I have print those dictionary name on `UITableView`.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"myCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
         cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [[self.personobjectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"Name"];
    return cell;
}
```

It will give me list of names in `UITableView`. I used a search bar and I want to search for specific words and have them show on my `UITableView`, but its not working using this code:

```
-(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText{

    if([searchText length] == 0){
        self.isfiltered = NO;
    }
    else{
        self.isfiltered = YES;
        NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[cd] %@",searchText];
        filteredList = [self.person filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
    }

    [self.mytable reloadData];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your data source array while searching .

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return   self.isfiltered ? filteredList.count : self.person.count;
}


-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath { static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"myCell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) { cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier]; }
cell.textLabel.text = [[ self.isfiltered ? filteredList : self.person objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"Name"]; }

   return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**you need to change 'SELF' -> 'Name'.**

```
    -(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText{

        if([searchText length] == 0){
            self.isfiltered = NO;
        }
        else{
            self.isfiltered = YES;
            NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Name contains[cd] %@",searchText];
            filteredList = [self.person filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
        }

        [self.mytable reloadData];
    }
```

**Then change in your table array.**

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

   if (self.isfiltered)
    return filteredList.count;
   else
    return  self.person.count;
}


-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath { static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"myCell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) { cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier]; }
if (self.isfiltered)
cell.textLabel.text = [[self.isfiltered objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"Name"];

else
 cell.textLabel.text = [[self.person objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"Name"];


   return cell;
}
```